# WordPress - не выводятся посты в рубрике (произвольный тип постов)

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть тип постов в рубриками, на странице рубрики должны выводится посты, если это стандартные посты, то они выводятся, если посты с мого типа постов, просто пишет что нет постов. 
Вот код вывода со страницы рубрики:

```
<div class="posts"><?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : 
  the_post(); // если посты есть - запускаем цикл wp ?>
  <?php get_template_part('loop'); // для отображения каждой записи берем шаблон loop.php ?>
  <?php endwhile; // конец цикла
  else: echo '<p>Нет записей.</p>'; endif; // если записей нет, выводим "Нет записей" ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение. Может кому то пригодится, нужно в function написать следующий код:

```
 function custom_post_type_cat_filter($query) {
  if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
  if ($query->is_category()) {
  $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'ТИП_ПОСТА' ) );
    }
   }
  }

add_action('pre_get_posts','custom_post_type_cat_filter');
```